# How to disabled the typeahead ng bootstrap control

Tags: typeahead, ng-bootstrap

How can I apply the disabled attr to the ngb typeahead?

ifi use [attr.disabled]  it complains disabled not part of element

Answer (score 2):

[Typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples), as any other Angular control, can be disabled by binding to the `disabled` *property* (and not an attribute): `[disabled]="expression"`.

You don't see the `disabled` property documented on the [API documentation page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api), ad the `disabled` property is part of the `ngModel`.

Here is an example in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lSUB6lBEGKKyndlIibDp?p=preview

Comment: I want ngbtypeahead item disabled or item selecting time don't close result popup.